# "Couldn't connect to database" error on Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, mysqli

I want to make an application on Android to view my database from MySQL, but my code doesn't work correctly. The Android device told me that it "Couldn't connect to database".

this is screenshot of my problem : http://s21.postimg.org/fwgx2o5if/aaa.png

This is my `MainActivity.java` code:

```
package com.example.bismillahirohamnirohim;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    TextView resultView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.enableDefaults(); // STRICT MODE ENABLED

        resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

        getData();

    }

    public void getData() {

        String result = "";

        InputStream isr = null;

        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://localhost/Myfile.php"); // YOUR PHP SCRIPT
                                                                // ADDRESS

            // HttpPost httppost = new
            // HttpPost("http://172.23.193.32/elift-test/myfile.php"); //YOUR
            // PHP SCRIPT ADDRESS

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            isr = entity.getContent();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());

            resultView.setText("Couldnt connect to database");

        }

        // convert response to string

        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }

            isr.close();

            result = sb.toString();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());

        }

        // parse json data

        try {

            String s = "";

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                s = s + "Name : " + json.getString("id") + " "
                        + json.getString("username");
            }

            resultView.setText(s);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            // TODO: handle exception

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());

        }

    }

}
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("jadwal");

$sql1=mysql_query("select * from jadwalkuliah ");

if (!$sql1) {

echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();

exit;

}

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))

$output[]=$row;


print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();

?>
```

I'm using XAMPP.

Please help me. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This has **NOTHING** to do with android. Android cannot talk to mysql directly. This is purely a PHP problem.

Comment: Please give us more information to solve your problem! Does it work, if you open the website in your browser?

Comment: @Marc B : so, what can I do? :'(
please help me :(                                                                speedy1034 : it can work correctly if I open the website in my browser.

Comment: Learn basic debugging. If you're being told that PHP cannot connect to the DB, figure out why. You've failed to confirm that you even connected. e.g. `$con = mysql_connect(....) or die(mysql_error());` would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have localhost in android code.
It must be

```
http://(system ip address)/Myfile.php
```

which you get under 
run>cmd>right click on cmd run as administrator **ipconfig**

Comment: I'm still can't solve the problem :( I was changed 'localhost' to my IP. but still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<html><body>
<form action="balance.php" method="GET">
<input type="date" name="date" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if(isset($_GET['date'])&&!empty($_GET['date']))
    {
        echo $date=$_GET['date'];

    mysql_select_db("thirumala", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT product.pcode,pname,brand,price,oldbal,receipt,total,current,sales.date FROM product,sales WHERE sales.date='$date' AND product.pcode=sales.pcode");

                    echo "<table border='1'>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Product Code</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>OB</th>
                    <th>Receipt</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th>Current</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    </tr>";
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['pcode'] . "</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>" . $row['pname'].  "</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>" . $row['brand'].  " </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['price'].  " </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['oldbal']. " </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['receipt']." </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['total'].  "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['current']." </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['date'];
                    echo "<br />";
}}else{
echo 'Enter Valid Date';}                   
mysql_close($con);
?>
</br><a href="index.html>Home</a>
</body></html>
```

Try This connection this might help...